# How do I add dynamic HTML to ASP.NET Razor

Tags: html, asp.net, windows, asp.net-web-api, razor-pages

In my index.cshtml file I have the following

```
@Model.Message
```

where Message is a property in my PageModel subclass.  In OnGet, I set Message, a string property, to the text I read from an HTML file named UnderConstruction.html.  Now, the file reads fine, but I want to display the contents in the HTML.  At first, since this is temporary, I was going to ignore this, but I realize I need to be able to read data from a database ad create HTML based on the results.  So, how do I add this HTML to my page.  As of now, the HTML tags are displaying

```
&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;&lt;div id=&quot;UnderConstruction&quot;&gt;Coming soon&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;&lt;p /&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;&lt;p /&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;&lt;p style=&quot;font-size: 36pt;&quot;&gt;We are planning a March 1, 2023 launch!&lt;br/&gt;See you soon!&lt;/p&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;&#x9;&lt;/div&gt;&#xD;&#xA;
```

NOT

```
<div id="UnderConstruction">Coming soon <p /> <p /> <p style="font-size: 36pt;">We are planning a March 1, 2023 launch!<br/>See you soon!</p> </div>
```

not the HTML it should render.  There is url encoding I think going on.  Please be kind, I cannot find the answer with Google or previous questions on this site.  You guys are literally my last hope.

Comment: It *sounds like* you're looking for the `@Html.Raw()` helper, unless I'm misunderstanding.  Though *be careful*, as emitting raw HTML from uncontrolled sources (e.g. user input) is an XSS problem waiting to happen.

Comment: I don't see that when I type it in the cshtml file

Comment: Honestly, you're probably better off structuring the `Message` a little better with the strings you want to display (maybe by storing json in the database or something and deserializing in your C#), then generating the html in the cshtml file.

Comment: I'm relatively new to ASP.net.  The last time I worked with ASP was '05/'06, so things have changed a little.  I copied some code someplace to try with the Message property, but the Html.Raw was a better choice.  But ultimately, I hope for my site to not be "Under Construction" forever, so even this will go away.

Comment: @GeneralGrievance,  I am trying to create an online newsletter.  I want to store information about the "articles" in a local mdf file.  Then I will query the table and put hyperlinked images in a dynamic HTML page based on the results.  How would you suggest I do this?

Comment: Oh, I see. If you have full control over the content, and write/generate the HTML yourself, you should be ok using `@Html.Raw()`. Just so long as you don't let random users submit whatever they want.